# iOS MDM override erase device passcode setting

Tags: mdm, ios-provisioning

Personal iPhone got MDM from company in order to get exchange email.
I want to disable the 10 passcode failures erases device setting.
But this setting is enabled and greyed out so I can't disable it.

Is there any way to override this single MDM setting to allow me to disable it?
Perhaps add a second profile or go in with a file browser to mod some OS file somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The company has established a security policy to control access to its data (in this case, your email server). You could delete the MDM profile, but you will lose access to Exchange.